# Change the text color,value and images in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have designed an Ember app in which I have photos feed page. Each picture contains a Like button, Like text and value corresponding to it. When I click on the like button, it should change like pic, color of text like, and its value. It is same as Facebook like button. I am not sure how to implement it in ember.

## feed.js

```
{{#each feedResult as |feed|}}    
<div class="scale">
           <img id = "image1" src = "{{feed.feedPhotos.0.photo_url}}"/>
           <div class="transhifive">
            {{#if feed.feedPhotos.0.is_liked}}
                <a href = "#" {{action 'unlike'}} >
                   <img  src = "images/ic-unlike-yellow.png">
                   <p>Hi Five! |</p>
                </a>
            {{else}}  
                <a href ="#" {{action 'like'}}>
                   <img src = "images/ic-like-white.png"/>
                   <p>Hi Five! |</p>
                </a>
            {{/if}} 
            <p>{{feed.feedPhotos.0.numlikes}}</p>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

## controller.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     session:service('session'),
     feedResult:Ember.computed('model',function() {

       "SOME MANIPULATION WITH MODEL DATA"

}),
hifive(){
        this.incrementProperty('feed.feedPhotos.0.numFives');
    }
  }
});
```

I thought this will atleast increase the like value but it is also throwing error.

```
Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "feed.feedPhotos.0" could not be found or was destroyed
```

How should I implement it so that it work exactly like Facebook's "Like button"?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to pass the feed you want to work with into your action...

```
<a href ="#" {{action 'unlike' feed}}>

<a href ="#" {{action 'like' feed}}>
```

2) add `actions` hash to your controller and write your unlike and like functionality...

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     session:service('session'),
     feedResult:Ember.computed('model',function() {
       "SOME MANIPULATION WITH MODEL DATA"
     }),
     hifive(){
        this.incrementProperty('feed.feedPhotos.0.numFives');
     }
     actions {
         like: function(feed) {}
         unlike: function(feed) {}
     }
  }
});
```

3) inside your `like` and `unlike` actions modify your feed values

```
like: function(feed) {
  //Depending on what is immutable you may need to toy around with how to set these variables
  feed.feedPhotos.0.set('is_liked', true);
  feed.feedPhotos.0.set('numlikes', feed.feedPhotos.0.get('numlikes') +1);

  feed.save();
}
```

4) rerender your view

```
 me.rerender()
```

`me` will need to be defined earlier in your controller as `this`

Comment: it throws a build error in "feed.feedPhotos.0..is_liked.set(true);"

Comment: oh wait... I think it needs to be `feed.feedPhotos.0.set('is_liked', true);` see updated code